# Memory mapped file C++

Tags: c++, file, winapi

please help me with reading memory mapped file. I open file in code below. And then i want to read bytes from 8 to 16. How can i do that?

```
// 0. Handle or create and handle file
m_hFile = CreateFile(file_path.c_str(), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if (m_hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
    {
        m_hFile = createNewFile(file_path.c_str());
    }
    else throw GetLastError();
}

// 1. Create a file mapping object for the file
m_hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(m_hFile, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 0, NULL);
if (m_hMapFile == NULL) throw GetLastError();

// 2. Map the view.
m_lpMapAddress = MapViewOfFile(m_hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0);
// to map
if (m_lpMapAddress == NULL) throw GetLastError();
```

Comment: Is a dublicate from this one: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889557/mapping-large-files-using-mapviewoffile). You have the pointer m_lpMapAddress, which is hopefully a byte pointer. Add 8 bytes to the pointer and read the memory. That's all

Comment: @mrAtari How can i add 8 bytes?

Comment: m_lpMapAddress +=8

Comment: @mrAtari: That won't work. `MapViewOfFile` returns `void*`. If the assignment to `m_lpMapAddress` works without a cast, then its type must be `void*` as well. You cannot use `operator+=` on a `void*`. You'll have to cast to a specific type (`unsigned char` for bytes) first.

Comment: Have you ever heard about pointer casting? char* cursor = (char*)m_lpMapAddress; cursor+=8;

Comment: @mrAtari: Given the fact, that I suggested you cast the `void*` to a specific type, it seems plausible, that I *"have [...] heard about [...] casting"*. What point are you trying to make?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access it like any other memory block. Here's an example that prints those bytes interpreted as `unsigned char`s:

```
unsigned char *mappedDataAsUChars = (unsigned char*)m_lpMapAddress;

for(int k = 8; k < 16; k++)
    std::cout << "Byte at " << k << " is " << mappedDataAsUChars[k] << std::endl;
```

Comment: is there more beautiful soulution? What if i want read bytes in structure?

Comment: @ExiD: A *"more beautiful"* way to access memory? None that I know of. More convoluted? Probably. But what exactly do you dislike about the canonical way to do it?

Comment: @ExiD You can easily do `MyStruct *mappedDataAsMyStruct = (MyStruct*)m_lpMapAddress;` or similar. Watch out for alignment that might make your structure not be laid out the way you want.

Comment: i am sorry for my english. I think it may use memcpy, but i am not sure.

Comment: @ExiD You can also use memcpy.

Comment: Define "more beautiful", @ExiD. Beauty is in the eye of the beholder. FWIW, this is a very clean and simple solution.